# passing a list to a role in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I need to read from a config file which needs to contain a list. The list needs to be passed to a role as argument.

```
---
- name: run command on localhost
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: read variables from file
    shell: cat {{ conf1/TMP.txt }}
    register: contents
- name: role to trigger the run script process
  hosts: otherhost
  roles:
    - { role: run_script, applist: "{{ contents }}"  }
```

The content of the conf1/TMP.txt file is as follows:

```
[ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
```

The above mentioned code segment is not working but the following code segment works:

```
---
- name: main yml file to trigger the whole process
  hosts: otherhost
  roles:
   - { role: run_script, applist: [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ] }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using a lookup filter instead of a shell command. Example below..

```
---
- name: run command on localhost
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        contents: "{{ lookup('file', 'tmp.txt')  }}"
    - debug: var=contents

- name: role to trigger the run script process
  hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - { role: foo, applist: "{{ contents  }}" }
```

The output of debug should look like this

```
ok: [localhost] => {
"foo": [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4"
]}
```

Comment: Hi linuxdynasty,
Thank you for your comments.
Currently it is passing "contents" as the value of applist to the role instead of [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]. Is there a way to resolve that?

Comment: Try passing it as a filter "{{ contents }}"

Comment: Already tried that option, it skips the task with undefined error.

Comment: Do you think is it problem because we are passing the variable to the role? Is there any other way to pass on the variable to the role.

Comment: @SouravDas I updated the answer to use set_fact instead of vars. I've tested this with a test role and worked as expected.

Comment: Not sure why "{{ contents  }}" is not working for me as I keep getting the following error: [DEPRECATION WARNING]: Skipping task due to undefined Error, in the future this will be a fatal error.. This feature will be removed in a future release. Deprecation warnings can be
 disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.

I am using ansible 2.0.1.0.